# LINQ convert DateTime to string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity

```
List<Post> list =
(
    from c in db.TitleComments
    join t in db.Titles on c.TitleId equals t.Id
    join u in db.Users on c.UserId equals u.Id
    where t.Id == _titleId && c.Date > time
    orderby c.Date descending
    select new Post { Username = u.Username, PostingDate = c.Date.ToString(), Data = c.Comment }
).ToList();
```

The code above causes exception on the convertion of date to string, PostingDate = c.Date.ToString(). Any ideas how to get around this?

Exception error:
{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: @BrunoLM, linq is trying to convert date to string using sql but since there is no ToString() method in sql it can't convert it, this behavior is by design i believe.

Comment: can you give us the exact exception. I dont believe that this is an error thrown in SQL.

Comment: srry I thought this was an hibernate question my bad..

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what @Joakim said.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*linq is trying to convert date to string using sql but since there is no ToString() method in sql it can't convert it, this behavior is by design* - Joakim

In other words, return the date itself and convert it to a string after it executes on SQL side:

```
(
select new { Username = u.Username,
    PostingDate = c.Date
    [...]
})
.ToList() // runs on SQL and returns to the application
.Select(o =>  // is not generating a SQL, it is running on the app
    new Post { Username = o.Username,
        PostingDate = o.PostingDate.ToString(),
        [...]
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remedy your problem by projecting into an anonymous type, and then at a later step project into `Post` after the data has already been returned from the DB.

```
(from ....
 select new { /* stuff */, Date = c.Date })
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(p => new Post { /* stuff */, PostingDate = p.Date.ToString() })
.ToList();
```

However, given that you have a property called *PostingDate*, the original source *being a date*, I would recommend your revise your object to actually keep the value as a `DateTime` instead of a string.

Comment: I feel that is what I will do, make PostingDate as DateTime type. I wanted to save the client from having to perform the date formatting, but it looks like it can't be helped in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this can be done in a direct way.

```
   var list =    
    select new Post { Username = u.Username, PostingDate =  SqlFunctions.StringConvert(c.Date), Data = c.Comment } 
from 
(from c in db.TitleComments
    join t in db.Titles on c.TitleId equals t.Id
    join u in db.Users on c.UserId equals u.Id
    where t.Id == _titleId && c.Date > time
    orderby c.Date descending).AsEnumerable()  
    ).ToList();
```

Also with EF4 you can try something like this:

```
List<Post> list =
(
from c in db.TitleComments
join t in db.Titles on c.TitleId equals t.Id
join u in db.Users on c.UserId equals u.Id
where t.Id == _titleId && c.Date > time
orderby c.Date descending
select new Post { Username = u.Username, PostingDate = SqlFunctions.DateName(c.Date), Data = c.Comment }
).ToList();
```